# ERR_INVALID_URL fetch node js

Tags: node.js

I use fetch method to fetch a local json file . But node returns a invalid url error

Node.js v18.15.0

Here is my code

fetch("./localites.json")
.then(Response=>console.log(Response))

And i have the file 'localites.json' in my directory

I was trying to fetch the json local file `your text`

Comment: When i try fetch("localites.json") i have the same error

Comment: Hi, please include endpoint code,  the part where you manage the request